# Vercel Sveltekit long build times due to treatment of static assets?

Tags: vercel, sveltekit

I've got a Sveltekit site deployed to Vercel. I'm using the SSG configuration (using adapter-static). The deploys are successful but the build times have gotten very long due to, it seems:

1. re-creation of static assets (mostly images) on each deploy.
2. duplication of static asset creation for client and server.

With regard to the second point, I'm not sure if this should be happening because I'm using static site generation.

Git [here](https://github.com/code-sanchu/alesh_compton-v1.1).

`/routes/+layout.ts`:

```
export const prerender = true;
```

My config:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
    },

    preprocess: vitePreprocess()
};
```

Abridged deploy log:

> Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1 (Hive) Cloning
> github.com/code-sanchu/alesh_compton-v1.1 (Branch: main, Commit:
> d53c032) Cloning completed: 3.338s Restored build cache Running
> "vercel build" Vercel CLI 32.5.6 Detected `pnpm-lock.yaml` version 6
> generated by pnpm 8 Installing dependencies... Lockfile is up to date,
> resolution step is skipped Packages: +4
> ++++ Done in 1.3s Running "pnpm run build" app-v1.1@0.0.1 build /vercel/path0 vite build ▲ [WARNING] Cannot find base config file
> "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json" [tsconfig.json]
> tsconfig.json:2:12:
> 2 │   "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
> ╵              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ vite v4.4.2 building SSR bundle for production... transforming... ✓ 2800 modules
> transformed. rendering chunks... vite v4.4.2 building for
> production... transforming... ✓ 2812 modules transformed. rendering
> chunks... computing gzip size...
>
> .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/version.json
> 0.03 kB │ gzip: 0.05 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/youtube-icon.06e8af7c.avif
> 1.66 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/youtube-icon.0b692429.webp
> 2.86 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/buy%20now%20Button.67f1fa5d.avif
> 3.55 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/youtube-icon.5134cc24.jpg
> 4.05 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/buy%20now%20Button.88ac1a88.webp
> 5.84 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/logo.cc812ab9.jpg
> 7.42 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/estat_du_france-yt_thumbnail.2ad4e782.avif
> 7.55 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/squatumentary_doc-yt_thumbnail.672b3a06.avif
> 8.73 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/slimey_skumbaagz-yt_thumbnail.e6a6ed7b.avif
> 9.08 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/logo.6c0741a1.avif
> 9.11 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/HOODIE.9a885f70.avif
> 10.53 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/Reversible%20Polo%20button.5848f8fb.avif
> 10.89 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/buy%20now%20Button.e56563cb.jpg
> 11.03 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/9.210d6d61.avif
> 11.06 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/6.4a2e5d2d.avif
> 11.47 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/logo.224d030d.webp
> 12.12 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/midnight-yt_thumbnail.3b3d398b.avif
> 14.37 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/kurukuru-yt_thumbnail.8a1f5232.avif
> 14.59 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/slimey_skumbaagz-yt_thumbnail.979aa7d2.webp
> 14.88 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/6.7d4f4a93.avif
> 15.69 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/televsion_god-yt_thumbnail.fbf847a2.avif
> 16.09 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/slimey_skumbaagz-yt_thumbnail.3dcc762f.jpg
> 16.44 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/squatumentary_doc-yt_thumbnail.2283d6a6.webp
> 17.25 kB .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/HOODIE.c3ad167a.webp
> 18.64 kB
>
> ...[more stuff cut out here]
>
> ✓ built in 12m 20s
> .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/youtube-icon.06e8af7c.avif
> 1.66 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/youtube-icon.0b692429.webp
> 2.86 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/buy%20now%20Button.67f1fa5d.avif
> 3.55 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/youtube-icon.5134cc24.jpg
> 4.05 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/buy%20now%20Button.88ac1a88.webp
> 5.84 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/logo.cc812ab9.jpg
> 7.42 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/estat_du_france-yt_thumbnail.2ad4e782.avif
> 7.55 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/squatumentary_doc-yt_thumbnail.672b3a06.avif
> 8.73 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/slimey_skumbaagz-yt_thumbnail.e6a6ed7b.avif
> 9.08 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/logo.6c0741a1.avif
> 9.11 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/HOODIE.9a885f70.avif
> 10.53 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/Reversible%20Polo%20button.5848f8fb.avif
> 10.89 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/buy%20now%20Button.e56563cb.jpg
> 11.03 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/9.210d6d61.avif
> 11.06 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/6.4a2e5d2d.avif
> 11.47 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/logo.224d030d.webp
> 12.12 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/midnight-yt_thumbnail.3b3d398b.avif
> 14.37 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/kurukuru-yt_thumbnail.8a1f5232.avif
> 14.59 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/slimey_skumbaagz-yt_thumbnail.979aa7d2.webp
> 14.88 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/6.7d4f4a93.avif
> 15.69 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/televsion_god-yt_thumbnail.fbf847a2.avif
> 16.09 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/slimey_skumbaagz-yt_thumbnail.3dcc762f.jpg
> 16.44 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/squatumentary_doc-yt_thumbnail.2283d6a6.webp
> 17.25 kB .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/HOODIE.c3ad167a.webp
> 18.64 kB

I'm expecting the same static assets not to be re-created on each deploy (i.e. a build cache to be used) and not be created twice on each deploy.

I feel I've followed the set-up correctly but maybe I've missed something?